# GA4 Audiences - Potential Bug - 'Within the same event' condition scoping

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Been currently running into an issue creating a GA4 audience created with the **'Within the same event'** condition scoping. It seems on GA4 the number of users is showing as **'<10 Users'** and returns no users when looking under the reporting for **User > User Attributes > Audiences**.

[image: Less than 10 Users Reported on GA4]

However on closer inspection of the audience we can indeed see in the summary plenty of eligible users for this audience. Also we have linked a Google Ads account to this GA4 account and can see the imported audience in Google Ads. It too also has users populating daily...

[image: Eligible Users for this audience and Linked Google Ads Audience]

We have also confirmed/checked the parameter Vehicle Condition 'Used' or 'used' is indeed being ingested into GA4 on a consistent daily basis.

[image: Vehicle Condition Parameter]

What could be potentially causing GA4 to report **'<10 Users'** under the Audience menu and show nothing in the audience reports? But are showing users populating everywhere else we look (summary section + linked Google Ads Audience)?

This seems to only occur with  **'Within the same event'** condition scoping, is this a bug? We've been able to replicate this on multiple GA4 properties, when using the **'Within the same event'** condition scoping: GA4 fails to register any users.